# mod_rewrite performance : several exact matches VS one regex

Tags: regex, performance, mod-rewrite, match

I use mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file and I have about 20 rewritings to do.

In terms of performance, is it better to make one rule with a regular expression :

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ page.php?category=$1 [L]
```

or is it better to make one rule per rewriting :

```
    RewriteRule category/one page.php?category=one [L]
    RewriteRule category/two page.php?category=two [L]
    RewriteRule category/three page.php?category=three [L]
    [...]
```

or is it better to make otherwise ?

Comment: I don't think this will make a real difference since all the strings that have been processed are very small strings. However, I haven't tested the two ways.

Comment: Better to have just one rule.